# How to stop Selenium clicking an element off-screen on iOS Safari?

Tags: c#, ios, selenium, safari

I have a problem when automating a webpage, I am using:

- C#
- iOS
- Safari

The problem is that I need to click on an image, this image is 75% off the bottom of the page. The problem is that because some of it is visible on the page Selenium can see it and therefore will try to click on it. When it clicks on it, it actually clicks the Safari menu; I think this is because it is trying to click the centre of the image, if the Safari menu wasn't there, then that's where the centre of the image would be.
I've attached 2 screenshots to illustrate this.
I have three questions

1. Is there a way to tell Selenium to automatically scroll any element into view before clicking on it?
2. Is there a way I can manually tell it to scroll down to any element?
3. Is there a way to tell Selenium to take into account the Safari bar so that it doesn't click it, ever?

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a id="3245248" class="detail-info" href="#">
<img title="Order Information" src="/Content/images/24x24/info.png"></a>
```

C#
You can click the image by passing id name:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#3245248 img")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have just found a solution which will scroll the element into view properly before trying to click on it. I have added this as a reply to my original post.